# The oauth state was missing or invalid - Unknown location

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth, google-oauth, .net-7.0

I am using both Google and Facebook authentication mechanisms in my .NET 7.0 app and they both work fine locally. When deployed in my DEV environment I am getting exceptions when coming back from Google/Facebook. So the challenge works correctly, I am able to authenticate at their side but the callback fails, saying:

```
Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
Unknown location
```

I am being redirected to `https://my.website.com/signin-google` with the state in a querystring parameter. This is the expected behavior as I did not configure an explicit callback path and by default it's set to `signin-google` and `signin-facebook`. But somehow it seems like the `RemoteAuthenticationHandler` does not think this matches the callback path so it's not handling the request? Or would the issue be in the `OAuthHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync`? Maybe when unprotecting the state data? But then why would this work locally?

My setup:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle("google", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.ClientId = AppSettings.Instance.GoogleClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = AppSettings.Instance.GoogleClientSecret;
    })
    .AddFacebook("facebook", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.AppId = AppSettings.Instance.FacebookAppId;
        options.AppSecret = AppSettings.Instance.FacebookAppSecret;
    });
```

Edit: Could this possibly be linked to the fact I am using 2 servers in my DEV environment and that it uses something machine-related to unprotect the state so it does not work when I land on the other machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was due to the fact I am now deploying the application on multiple distributed servers, accessed via a load balancer.
This article [here](https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-the-data-protection-system-in-asp-net-core/) helped me to understand how data protection works in ASP.NET Core.

By default key-rotation system is used and the keys are generated by the machine and persisted to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys`. So of course this does not work anymore when you scale up your applications.

So instead I decided to store the data protection keys in a shared database so all machines will use the same key:

1. Add reference to Nuget `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore`.
2. Create a DbContext that inherits from `IDataProtectionKeyContext`
3. Register your DbContext
4. Setup your data protection to use the DbContext as:

   ```
   builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
       .PersistKeysToDbContext<DataProtectionKeyContext>();
   ```